# Trying to learn regex

Tags: java, regex

Hello everyone I'm trying to learn regex from java website and I try to run this JAVA program but each time I get No Console output, what do I do ? here is the url :

http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/regex/test_harness.html

I'm trying this inside eclipse

**UPDATE :**

Can anybody suggest some other better way to learn regex

Comment: you might be getting the console output but it is getting closed, try putting a console.readline() or something so that it stops after it puts something to the console, so that u can check it

Comment: I found 'egrep' to be the easiest way to learn and test regex.

Comment: I had already learned regex by the time I stumbled across Rubular (http://rubular.com), but it seems like a great place for a beginner to experiment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I highly suggest doing two things:

1. Read the first two chapters of Mastering Regular Expressions
2. Buy Regex Buddy.  It's a little helper program that holds your hand with using and explaining all the tokens and grouping options.  It lets you test your expressions on text you're using and also generates code snippets in many different languages.  I started using it when I needed regex solutions and it brought me up the learning curve fast.  Now I don't need it, but I still use it to test out some complex named group matches I do for batch file parsing. [Regex Buddy Website](http://www.regexbuddy.com/)

Answer (score 2):

Are you running the application in an IDE such as Eclipse or IntelliJ IDEA? Try using the command line instead. Some IDEs will screw up calls to `System.console()`.

Comment: @Samir Talwar I'm using it inside eclipse, how do I use command line isntead ?

Comment: Go into your "bin" directory (or wherever Eclipse is outputting your ".class" files) using the `cd` command and run `java MyClassName`. If the class is in a package, prefix it: `java my.package.name.MyClassName`. If that doesn't work, should and tell us what OS you're using.

Answer (score 1):

I had to learn RegEx one year ago.
I used [Wikipedia page for regex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) and these these two sites to test online the regex I needed ([Site1](http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx), [Site2](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/)) instead of using regex from UltraEdit...

It is not as difficult as you could think at the beginning

Answer (score 0):

Yes, what Samir said is correct. You can test if your IDE supports the console by doing this:

```
if (System.console() == null)
{
    System.out.println("No console supported! :-(");
} else
{
    System.out.println("Console supported! :-)");
}
```

You can read the java-doc about `System.console();` [here](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#console%28%29)

There can you see `null` will be returned if there isn't a console.

### To answer your second question

To print something:

```
System.out.println("Here your text you want to print");
```

To read something:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String oneWord = scanner.next();
String oneLine = scanner.next("\n");
```

or:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String line = br.readLine();
```

Hope this helps, and you can continue learning regexes!

Comment: Dunno I didn't vote you down +1

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to learn regex with Perl. Its much better integrated than with Java

Answer (score 0):

Use this website: http://www.fileformat.info/tool/regex.htm

Internally, it uses the `java.util.regex` package, so you can worry about learning regex and still have your knowledge directly transfer to regex in Java when you need it.

Answer (score 0):

You could try different kinds of regular expressions with eclipses find/replace (or with some none ide text editor that supports regex).

Python or Ruby interactive shells are good places to test regex (and regex syntax is much nicer than in Java).

And of course there's the internet.